# URL from a function for href not acting the same as a string

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sites

I am trying to get the URL to change depending on the results of a function. 
 If the href is a string, it will go to the google site page I want.  Using a function however does not result in the same behaviour.  Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong?

Script HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <?var previewURL = PageForPreview();?><a href="#" onClick="window.open<?=previewURL?>" id="link" target="_blank" ></a> 
    <!-- < ?var previewURL = PageForPreview();?><a href="< ?=previewURL?>" id="link" target="_blank" ></a> document.location.href=//-->
    <!-- <a href="#" onClick="document.location.href=PageForPreview();" id="link" target="_blank" ></a>//-->
    <!-- <a href="https://sites.google.com/a/ENTER A SITE" id="link" target="_blank" ></a> //-->
  </body>
  <script>
    document.getElementById("link").click();
    //google.script.host.close();
  </script>
</html>
```

Code.gs

```
////### go to preview page
function PageForPreview() {
  var site = SitesApp.getActiveSite();
  var newchildPages = site.getAllDescendants();
  for(var ii in newchildPages) {
    if (newchildPages[ii].getName() === "PreviewName") {
      var arrLatest = ii;
    } 
  }
  var previewURL = newchildPages[arrLatest].getUrl();
  Logger.log("prev = "+previewURL);
  return previewURL;
}
```

It is my intention to have a button on a google site that will run a web app.  The script runs okay until i try to open the page (section above) but then just displays the current page in a new window.  When I deploy the code from the script editor, it works as expected using a text string for the site URL but with the function, it opens the macro url in a new window and then another window with the url https://n-ycp7azn7ycatih3bdzb2ibru6gld2ohyqxhk4xy-0lu-script.googleusercontent.com/userCodeAppPanel#

So I have a problem with the string in the href not acting in the same way and also the button on my page not going to the preview page even with the href as a string.

My next thing to investigate will be JSONP but I have very little experience with any coding.  https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/content#serving_jsonp_in_web_pages  Any guidance appreciated.

Edit
I am now able to get the desired page shown when deploying the web app from the script editor.  Still can't get it to show when pressing a button on the google site to deploy the web app.  Not sure if it's something with my code or the HTML for the button (or it just isn't possible).

```
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><base target="_top"></head><script>'
  +'var a = document.createElement("a"); a.href="'+PageForPreview()+'"; a.target="_blank";'
  +'if(document.createEvent){'
    +'var event=document.createEvent("MouseEvents");'
    +'event.initEvent("click",true,true);'
    +'a.dispatchEvent(event);'
  +'}else{'
    +'a.click()'
  +'}'
  //+'google.script.host.close();'
  +'</script></html>').setWidth( 90 ).setHeight( 10 );
  output.setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog( myhtml, "Please Wait..." );
```

Comment: To call `PageForPreview()` use `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler('handlername').PageForPreview();` take a look at the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#success_handlers).

Comment: Thanks for that Cooper.  I was able to get it working by creating the HTML in a function - I'll edit above as it may not be doing what I think it is.